# Overwrite angulars peer dependency

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, npm

We roll out different apps that are built using ionic, which is having a peer dependency of node-sass. We build our images on raspberry, which is not a supported architecture of node-sass. So for every project, we have to build node-sass, which takes about 20 to 30 minutes per project. Can we somehow reference it in the package.json files, that we use our own binary located on the system?

Comment: Why don't you, instead of installing it on every RB, change SASS and use LESS ? (Just asking if it would suit your needs, otherwise I don't know sorry)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option. Especially if you already have a big codebase. Ionic does not come with LESS and the generators create sass files too. This is too much of overhead for us, when only the binary is a problem.